# Could not initialize class org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultExchangeStrategiesBuilder

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I'm using spring webclient to make some server calls, but apparently the client is even failing to start up throwing the error
`Could not initialize class org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultExchangeStrategiesBuilder`. The dependency I have in my build.gradle is:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework:spring-webflux:5.1.5.RELEASE"
    implementation "io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:0.8.5.RELEASE"
    compileOnly "log4j:log4j:1.2.17"
    implementation "org.json:json:20140107"
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
}
```

and the following is the snippet of how I create the client

```
       WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(SOME_URL)
                .defaultHeaders(httpHeaders -> {
                    httpHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
                    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                    httpHeaders.set("User-Agent", "some name");
                })
                .build();
```

the error is coming from the builder, I know the error is from some dependency mess, but not sure what exactly am I missing in this case.

Comment: I did have the same issue, the original exception is catched in Class org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder. My issue was coming from different versions of Jackson libraries in the classpath (mixing 2.9, 2.10 & 2.11 !)